# join query optimization

Tags: mysql, sql, join, query-optimization, inner-join

recently I come up with some mysql performance issues, here's the query:

```
select
        assoc.id                    as id,
        parentNode.id               as parentNodeId,
        parentNode.version          as parentNodeVersion,
        parentStore.protocol        as parentNodeProtocol,
        parentStore.identifier      as parentNodeIdentifier,
        parentNode.uuid             as parentNodeUuid,
        childNode.id                as childNodeId,
        childNode.version           as childNodeVersion,
        childStore.protocol         as childNodeProtocol,
        childStore.identifier       as childNodeIdentifier,
        childNode.uuid              as childNodeUuid,
        assoc.type_qname_id         as type_qname_id,
        assoc.child_node_name_crc   as child_node_name_crc,
        assoc.child_node_name       as child_node_name,
        assoc.qname_ns_id           as qname_ns_id,
        assoc.qname_localname       as qname_localname,
        assoc.is_primary            as is_primary,
        assoc.assoc_index           as assoc_index


    from
        alf_child_assoc assoc
        join alf_node parentNode on (parentNode.id = assoc.parent_node_id)
        join alf_store parentStore on (parentStore.id = parentNode.store_id)
        join alf_node childNode on (childNode.id = assoc.child_node_id)
        join alf_store childStore on (childStore.id = childNode.store_id)

    where
        parentNode.id = 837
    order by
        assoc.assoc_index ASC,
        assoc.id ASC;
```

The problem is that the query took too long sorting and sending result set.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance

some count info:

```
mysql> select count(id) from alf_child_assoc;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|   7208882 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (12.51 sec)

mysql> select count(id) from alf_node;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|   3986059 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (1.68 sec)

mysql> select count(id) from alf_store;
+-----------+
| count(id) |
+-----------+
|         6 |
+-----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

This is the `explain` output:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type   | possible_keys                                                       | key            | key_len | ref                      | rows   | Extra          |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parentNode  | const  | PRIMARY,store_id,fk_alf_node_store,will_store_node_idx              | PRIMARY        | 8       | const                    |      1 | Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parentStore | const  | PRIMARY                                                             | PRIMARY        | 8       | const                    |      1 |                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | assoc       | ref    | parent_node_id,fk_alf_cass_pnode,fk_alf_cass_cnode,idx_alf_cass_pri | parent_node_id | 8       | const                    | 275218 | Using where    |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | childNode   | eq_ref | PRIMARY,store_id,fk_alf_node_store,will_store_node_idx              | PRIMARY        | 8       | repo.assoc.child_node_id |      1 |                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | childStore  | eq_ref | PRIMARY                                                             | PRIMARY        | 8       | repo.childNode.store_id  |      1 |                |
+----+-------------+-------------+--------+---------------------------------------------------------------------+----------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Below is some table-related informations:

```
mysql> desc alf_child_assoc;
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version             | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| parent_node_id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type_qname_id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| child_node_name_crc | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| child_node_name     | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| child_node_id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| qname_ns_id         | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| qname_localname     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| qname_crc           | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| is_primary          | bit(1)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| assoc_index         | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
12 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc alf_node;
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id             | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version        | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| store_id       | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| uuid           | varchar(36)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| transaction_id | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| node_deleted   | bit(1)       | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| type_qname_id  | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| locale_id      | bigint(20)   | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| acl_id         | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| audit_creator  | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| audit_created  | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| audit_modifier | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| audit_modified | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| audit_accessed | varchar(30)  | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
14 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> desc alf_store;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | bigint(20)   | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| version      | bigint(20)   | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| protocol     | varchar(50)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| identifier   | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| root_node_id | bigint(20)   | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> 
mysql> show index from alf_node;
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table    | Non_unique | Key_name             | Seq_in_index | Column_name    | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| alf_node |          0 | PRIMARY              |            1 | id             | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          0 | store_id             |            1 | store_id       | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          0 | store_id             |            2 | uuid           | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | idx_alf_node_del     |            1 | node_deleted   | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | idx_alf_node_txn_del |            1 | transaction_id | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | idx_alf_node_txn_del |            2 | node_deleted   | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | fk_alf_node_acl      |            1 | acl_id         | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | fk_alf_node_txn      |            1 | transaction_id | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | fk_alf_node_store    |            1 | store_id       | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | fk_alf_node_tqn      |            1 | type_qname_id  | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | fk_alf_node_loc      |            1 | locale_id      | A         |          18 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | will_store_node_idx  |            1 | id             | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_node |          1 | will_store_node_idx  |            2 | store_id       | A         |     3890448 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+----------+------------+----------------------+--------------+----------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
13 rows in set (0.01 sec)

mysql> show index from alf_store;
+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table     | Non_unique | Key_name          | Seq_in_index | Column_name  | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| alf_store |          0 | PRIMARY           |            1 | id           | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_store |          0 | protocol          |            1 | protocol     | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_store |          0 | protocol          |            2 | identifier   | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_store |          1 | fk_alf_store_root |            1 | root_node_id | A         |           6 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------+------------+-------------------+--------------+--------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> show index from alf_child_assoc;
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table           | Non_unique | Key_name           | Seq_in_index | Column_name         | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| alf_child_assoc |          0 | PRIMARY            |            1 | id                  | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          0 | parent_node_id     |            1 | parent_node_id      | A         |      632375 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          0 | parent_node_id     |            2 | type_qname_id       | A         |      632375 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          0 | parent_node_id     |            3 | child_node_name_crc | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          0 | parent_node_id     |            4 | child_node_name     | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | fk_alf_cass_pnode  |            1 | parent_node_id      | A         |      695612 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | fk_alf_cass_cnode  |            1 | child_node_id       | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | fk_alf_cass_tqn    |            1 | type_qname_id       | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | fk_alf_cass_qnns   |            1 | qname_ns_id         | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | idx_alf_cass_qncrc |            1 | qname_crc           | A         |     3478063 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | idx_alf_cass_qncrc |            2 | type_qname_id       | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | idx_alf_cass_qncrc |            3 | parent_node_id      | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | idx_alf_cass_pri   |            1 | parent_node_id      | A         |     1159354 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | idx_alf_cass_pri   |            2 | is_primary          | A         |     1159354 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | idx_alf_cass_pri   |            3 | child_node_id       | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | will_order_idx     |            1 | assoc_index         | A         |          16 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| alf_child_assoc |          1 | will_order_idx     |            2 | id                  | A         |     6956126 |     NULL | NULL   |      | BTREE      |         |               |
+-----------------+------------+--------------------+--------------+---------------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
17 rows in set (0.16 sec)
```

after read @Solarflare's answer, I tried it out, now the query becomes:

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
    assoc.id AS id,
    parentNode.id AS parentNodeId,
    parentNode.version AS parentNodeVersion,
    parentStore.protocol AS parentNodeProtocol,
    parentStore.identifier AS parentNodeIdentifier,
    parentNode.uuid AS parentNodeUuid,
    childNode.id AS childNodeId,
    childNode.version AS childNodeVersion,
    childStore.protocol AS childNodeProtocol,
    childStore.identifier AS childNodeIdentifier,
    childNode.uuid AS childNodeUuid,
    assoc.type_qname_id AS type_qname_id,
    assoc.child_node_name_crc AS child_node_name_crc,
    assoc.child_node_name AS child_node_name,
    assoc.qname_ns_id AS qname_ns_id,
    assoc.qname_localname AS qname_localname,
    assoc.is_primary AS is_primary,
    assoc.assoc_index AS assoc_index
FROM
    alf_child_assoc assoc FORCE INDEX (will_subq_idx)
        JOIN
    alf_node parentNode ON (parentNode.id = assoc.parent_node_id)
        JOIN
    alf_node childNode ON (childNode.id = assoc.child_node_id)
        JOIN
    alf_store parentStore ON (parentStore.id = parentNode.store_id)
        JOIN
    alf_store childStore ON (childStore.id = childNode.store_id)
WHERE
    parentNode.id = 550
ORDER BY assoc.assoc_index ASC , assoc.id ASC;
```

and the explain shows:

```
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table       | partitions | type   | possible_keys                                                         | key           | key_len | ref                      | rows   | filtered | Extra                                 |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | assoc       | NULL       | ref    | will_subq_idx                                                         | will_subq_idx | 8       | const                    | 303104 |   100.00 | Using index condition; Using filesort |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parentNode  | NULL       | const  | PRIMARY,store_id,fk_alf_node_store,will_store_node_idx,will_store_idx | PRIMARY       | 8       | const                    |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | childNode   | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,store_id,fk_alf_node_store,will_store_node_idx,will_store_idx | PRIMARY       | 8       | repo.assoc.child_node_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | parentStore | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,will_store_idx                                                | PRIMARY       | 8       | repo.parentNode.store_id |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | childStore  | NULL       | eq_ref | PRIMARY,will_store_idx                                                | PRIMARY       | 8       | repo.childNode.store_id  |      1 |   100.00 | NULL                                  |
+----+-------------+-------------+------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------------------------------+---------------+---------+--------------------------+--------+----------+---------------------------------------+
5 rows in set, 1 warning (0.03 sec)
```

this is the query plan showed by mysql workbench:

[image]

Thanks for you guys, you're awesome!

Comment: i have tried tuning the sort buffer related variables; adding index with the ORDER BY keys, but none helped. The result set is about 140k records, 32M bytes.

Answer (score 1):

The relevant key you need here is `alf_store(parent_node_id, child_node_id)`. You have the index `idx_alf_cass_pri` with `(parent_node_id, is_primary, child_node_id)` that is not used.

Please try the following steps to optimize your query:

Create the index `alf_store(parent_node_id, child_node_id)`.

A second index you might need later is `alf_node(id, store_id, version, uuid)` (you can change the order of `version` and `uuid`, depending on other use cases), so add it now too.

Execute/Explain the following central query

```
select parentNode.id as parentNodeID, childnode.id as childNodeID, 
       assoc.id as assocID
from alf_node as parentNode
join alf_child_assoc as assoc on (parentNode.id = assoc.parent_node_id)
join alf_node childNode on (childNode.id = assoc.child_node_id)
where parentNode.id = 837;
```

This will determine the minimal run time of your query. Based on your tables sizes and given timings, it should take about 0.5 seconds, at least if you run it a second time to have everything buffered (and of course the time required to return the rows, so do `select count(*) from alf_store as ...` for testing this time).

The next step is to join this with the store tables and fetching the remaining columns from the table. There are some possible methods that should, in a perfect database, perform the same, but in reality depend a little on your table contents, you might have to test it:

```
select assoc.id as id, 
       ...
from (
   select parentNode.id as parentNodeID, childnode.id as childNodeID, 
          assoc.id as assocID
   from alf_node as parentNode
   join alf_child_assoc as assoc on (parentNode.id = assoc.parent_node_id)
   join alf_node childNode on (childNode.id = assoc.child_node_id)
   where parentNode.id = 837
) as subquery
join alf_child_assoc assoc on (assoc.id = subquery.assocID)
join alf_node parentNode on (parentNode.id = subquery.parentnodeID)
-- join alf_store parentStore on (parentStore.id = parentNode.store_id)
join alf_node childNode on (childNode.id = subquery.childNodeID)
-- join alf_store childStore on (childStore.id = childNode.store_id)
order by
    assoc.assoc_index ASC,
    assoc.id ASC;
```

In a first step, leave away the 6 rows from store information - they should have no impact, but might screw something up, so test without them first; if they make an impact, there are ways to force mysql to optimize it correctly.

The covering index `alf_node(id, store_id, version, uuid)` from before should give you a better result on the outer join, so add it now if you haven't yet. You might add other covering indexes, but the only usefull other index would be on assoc, and that would mean basically all data in the table, and that might be overkill.

Always check the explains to see if the inner subquery still is the same, especially if it gets slower at one point. You might have to force mysql to use the correct index, because it might take another optimization (that can be correct, but can be wrong).

It might still take you some seconds to do all the lookups, depending on your data, data fragmentation and some other things.

Another option would be to gradually add the outer information to the inner query so you can skip some of the additional joins that I introduced on the outer query again:

```
select assoc.id as id, 
       ...
       subquery.ParentNodeVersion,
       subquery.ParentNodeUuid,
       ...
from (
   select parentNode.id as parentNodeID, childnode.id as childNodeID, 
          assoc.id as assocID, 
          parentNode.store_Id as ParentNodeStoreID,
          parentNode.Version as ParentNodeVersion,
          parentNode.uuid as ParentNodeUuid,
          childNode.store_Id as ChildNodeStoreID,
          childNode.Version as ChildNodeVersion,
          childNode.uuid as ChildNodeUuid
   from alf_node as parentNode
   join alf_child_assoc as assoc on (parentNode.id = assoc.parent_node_id)
   join alf_node childNode on (childNode.id = assoc.child_node_id)
   where parentNode.id = 837
) as subquery
join alf_child_assoc assoc on (assoc.id = subquery.assocID)
-- join alf_store parentStore on (parentStore.id = subquery.parentNodeStoreId)
-- join alf_store childStore on (childStore.id = subquery.ChildNodeStoreID)
order by
    assoc.assoc_index ASC,
    assoc.id ASC;
```

Again, start with a version without stores, and it can be better to add them inside the subquery, too.

This is sometimes a little try and error to optimize the subquery and/or covering indexes, you might test, check explains and ask again if you get a specific bottleneck.

The third option is to use your original query (that would be the equivalent of gradually inserting all columns inside the subquery, thus making it not a subquery anymore).

All options should actually have the same performance with this indexes because they express the same thing, but unfortunately that isn't always the reality, because it depends on correct statistics, and these aren't perfect, so you have to test it a bit.

But as I said: the main point is to use the right index on the central 3-table-join, the other point is to try to reduce table lookups by e.g. covering indexes or reordering the query.

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried it out, and the sub query executes as you expected, it tooks about 0.3 seconds, but the sub-query has a very large result set, and this is the profile:

Comment: executing                      | 0.000004 |
| Sending data                   | 0.267772 |
| init                           | 0.000128 |
| Creating tmp table             | 0.000040 |
| executing                      | 0.000003 |
| Copying to tmp table           | 0.460175 |
| converting HEAP to MyISAM      | 0.155992 |
| Copying to tmp table on disk   | 0.583183 |
| Sorting result                 | 0.180695 |
| Sending data                   | 0.687862 |
| end                            | 0.000014 |
| removing tmp table             | 0.058919 |

Comment: @oxnz I'm not sure if this is an "well, everything is fine and fast now", "the first step is fine now, I will try the rest next" or "I still get a lot of results"-comment. If your query has 140k records, it will take a while to send them, there is little you can do to if you need them all. Or are you just looking for a way to only send some of them to your client. Then you can just add `limit 20` or `limit 20,100` to the end to only send some of the results.

Comment: Thank you very much! I tried some tweaks but non of them worked, as you say, the result set is too large, and must be sorted, so the original query is already optimised. But not on a new version, the updated query and plan in my question is on a new version of MySQL 5.7.12. Any way, thanks again, I learn a lot from your answer.

Comment: @oxnz I'm not sure if the filesort is a big deal, but if you want to try it without, you can use the index `alf_child_assoc(parent_node_id, assoc_index, id, child_node_id)` (and maybe force it). I would only keep it if it really has a positive impact, it is a really special index for just this exact query, and spamming indexes will use space and increase overhead for inserts and updates. But it will give you the list already ordered, maybe it's the final kick. And I just realized I wrote `alf_store(parent_node_id, child_node_id)` all the time in my anwer, glad you understood it anyway...

Answer (score 0):

You can split the single large query to multiple parts in temporary tables and then merge the final result set..

```
with tmp1 as (
    SELECT table1.column1, table2.column2...
    FROM table1 JOIN table2
    ON table1.common_field = table2.common_field),

tmp2 as (
    SELECT table3.column1, table4.column2...
    FROM table3 JOIN table4
    ON table3.common_field = table4.common_field)

select a.column1, a.column2, b.column1, b.column2 .. from tmp1 a join tmp2 b on a.Something = b.Something;
```

Answer (score 0):

Overall looks ok.  I would suggest adding the following index

```
table           index
alf_child_assoc ( parent_node_id, child_node_id, assoc_index, id )
```

Second, since your query is lagging, I would try the keyword "STRAIGHT_JOIN" and change the explicit order of your from/join criteria to the following

```
SELECT STRAIGHT_JOIN
      ... all your fields...
   from
      alf_node parentNode 
         join alf_store parentStore 
            on parentNode.store_id = parentStore.id
         join alf_child_assoc assoc
            on parentNode.id = assoc.parent_node_id
            join alf_node childNode 
               on assoc.child_node_id = childNode.id
               join alf_store childStore 
                  on childNode.store_id = childStore.id
   ... rest of query where/order by...
```

SOMETIMES (not all), the STRAIGHT_JOIN tells MySql to run the query in the exact order as you have the tables listed.  The rest of your indexes appear to be ok (with the one exception I think should be added).  By putting the ParentNode alias in the first position and in the WHERE clause, STRAIGHT_JOIN MIGHT help the engine on trying to guess which table to put in the first position querying and such.

I have used this in another system querying government grants/contracts millions of records and the master table joins to over 20 lookup tables.  Query hung after 24 hrs.  Added STRAIGHT_JOIN, query finished in less than 2hrs.  Yes, we were expecting a lot of data though.